# Pegar 1 registro por data, sem repetir a data

Tags: mysql, sql

tenho um sistema de caixa aonde toda vez que o caixa é aberto e fechado por dia é registrado na tabela, o caixa é aberto e fechado várias vezes ao dia, porém eu gostaria de pegar apenas a primeira abertura do dia e com isso listar os últimos 30 dias mostrando apenas a primeira abertura de cada dia.

Como montar um select para funcionar desta maneira? já tentei limit, top1 mais nada disso funcionou para mim.

Obrigado.

Comment: coloca o sql que você já tem pronto

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você seleciona o Dia (Data sem horário) e depois você usa a função MIN na data e hora, agrupando pelo dia. Exemplo:

```
select
    cast(c.data as date) as dia,
    min(c.data) as abertura
from caixas c
group by cast(c.data as date);
```

> Resultado:

```
dia         abertura
2017-05-01  2017-05-01T10:41:23Z
2017-05-02  2017-05-02T18:40:28Z
2017-05-03  2017-05-03T18:40:31Z
```

Comment: deu pra entender, e quando o campo estiver com horário? existe alguma solução sem precisar mexer na minha estrutura atual?

Comment: repare que usei o mesmo campo nas duas colunas, e tem horário... usei o `cast` para converter para `date` que elimina o horário....

Comment: aproveitando, não tem a ver com a resposta, mas sim com a pergunta. Acesse o [Tour] pra ver como perguntar melhor e não receber esses votos negativos. Quando uma resposta solucionar seu problema, marque-a tambem!